# Close all processes created by System when abruptly closed

Tags: java, process

My Java programme starts several other Java processes. When the programme is closed, all created processes should be terminated.

If the programme is stopped via an internal stop command, all data can be saved and the processes shut down. I use a shutdown hook for this, and it works very well so far.

But if the programme terminates abruptly or is not closed correctly by the user, all processes remain running and the programme does not work the next time it is started.

How can I make it so that code is executed when the programme stops abruptly, or rather, how can I stop the processes?

As suggested, I should have included some code. Here is a **simplified** version of the code:

Class which starts the process:

```
@Override
public void startProcess() throws IOException {

    String command = "java -jar server.jar nogui";
    this.process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, new CloudFolder(super.getPath()).get());

    final InputReader reader = new InputReader();
    reader.open();

    String in = reader.getInput();

    if (in.equals("stop")) {

        this.process.destroy();
        this.process.getOutputStream().close();

    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    // normally the startProcess() Method would be
    // called right here.

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            
            // Just to see if it worked
            File file = new File("closing");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
    }, "Shutdown-thread"));

}
```

Comment: Please add some code or link to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Umeshwaran Thanks for the criticism, of course it's right. Post has been updated!